# Why the nav-link items don't turn white in this dark Bootstrap 4 Nav?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Why nav-link color doesn't turn white for this dark Bootstrap 4 [Nav](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/) code snippet? I mean, they should work as [Navbars](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/). Shouldn't they?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">

<main role="main">
  <div class="row navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="nav">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Growing</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Know</a>
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">What's New</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</main>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

**EDIT**: I've added a third item, to make more clear the horizontal layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing some of the proper semantics of Bootstrap.

- Your nav should be wrapped in actual `<nav>` tags.
- Your anchor tags should be wrapped in `<li>` tags.
- you're not using the proper classes that usually go with the `<ul>` tag.

FYI: Note that there is a none-responsive (layout will stay horizontal) and a responsive layout (layout will shift into a vertical orientation on smaller screens).

Example of proper Bootstrap nav semantics
(non-responsive, items will stay in a horizontal layout):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main role="main">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Growing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Know</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">What's New</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Example of proper Bootstrap nav semantics (responsive):

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<main role="main">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Growing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Know</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">What's New</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</main>
```

Comment: FYI, the use of `nav` elements is discretionary. It depends on your overall page structure. Bootstrap doesn't care.

Comment: Thanks but the resulting links are not horizontal as in the OP.

Comment: I've edited the question to make more clear the horizontal layout.

Comment: @abenci they are. They are just "responsive". See it in a bigger layout (press the "full page" link), and they will be horizontally aligned. It makes sense to have a responsive layout. Imagine having horizontal menu item on a smaller width. It'd be a horrible UX.

Comment: You are using a `navbar` not a `nav` as in the OP. In the OP there is no need to maximize to see the horizontal orientation.

Comment: @abenci responsive layouts are the way to go, usually. If you wish for the nav items to stay in a horizontal layout, then all that's needed is to remove the responsive class(es). See updated answer.